# Add dynamic field on Update in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

From mongoose doc

```
var thingSchema = new Schema({..}, { strict: false });
var thing = new Thing({ iAmNotInTheSchema: true });
thing.save(); // iAmNotInTheSchema is now saved to the db!!
```

It also says

> NOTE: Any key/val set on the instance that does not exist in your
>   schema is always ignored, regardless of schema option.

My Question is why is this?

What if I want to perform a Update on this and want to add few more fields in Schema is there a way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When performing an [update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update), you can use the `{strict: false}` option to allow the update to modify fields not defined in your schema:

```js
Thing.update({_id: 1}, {$set: {iAmNotInTheSchema: true}}, {strict: false}, cb);
```